# Setting the milliseconds on Timeout based on given date time

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I need help with setting my timeout for the function. I'm trying to set the timeout for a given date and time but my conversion of them to milliseconds is not working.

Here's my code. Please help.

```
<script>
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("Message");
var newRef = ref.child("20161227125916539")
newRef.on('value',function(snap){
    heading.innerText =snap.child("message").val();
});

ref.on("child_added",function(snap){

    var date = snap.child("date").val();
    var time = snap.child("time").val();
    var type = snap.child("type").val();
    var venue = snap.child("venue").val();
    var route = snap.child("route").val();
    var message = snap.child("message").val();

     date = date + time;
    date = date.getTime();
    var now = new Date();
    now = now.getTime();
    set = date - now;

    var explode = function(){
          alert("Boom!");
        };
        setTimeout(explode, 2000);


});
</script>
```

Comment: What is the value of `date` and `time`?

Comment: the value of the dates are in 2016-12-27 format and the value of the time is in 15:30 format

Comment: date=new date(date); the string needs to be converted to a date object

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the `date` using `new Date()`. 
As you said, the value of `date` is `"2016-12-27"` and the value of `time` is `"15:30"`, so while concatenating them, you also need an extra space. Something like:

```
date = date + " " + time;
var someDate = new Date(date);
var now = new Date();
var diffInMillis = now - someDate

var explode = function(){
    alert ("Boom!");
}

setTimeout(explode, diffInMillis);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dateobj=new Date(datestring);
timeinmilliseconds=dateobj.getTime();
//by the way, may check the browsers console if sth is not working:
datestring.getTime();// error:undefined function
```

Youre calling the getTime function on a string. You need to convert it into a time obj first. Be aware of the right String format. There are good resources online.

**The better Way:**

A timeout is killed when the browser is reloaded. Thats bad. It would be better to store the time, and regularily check if the time is reached. That would survive reloads, crashes, shutdowns etc:

```
function set(timestring){
 localStorage.setItem("timer",new Date(timestring).getTime());//store timer
 check();//start checking
}
function check(){
if(var await=localStorage.getItem("timer")){//if timer is set
   var now=new Date().getTime()
   if(await<=now){//time reached, or reached in the past
     alert("Yay, timer finished");
   }else{//not reached yet
     console.log(await-now+" left");//log the time left
     setTimeout(check,1000);//check again in a scond
    }}
   window.onload=check;// browser started, check for an existing timer
```

Use like this:

```
set("28-12-2016 12:30");
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the advise this is really helpful